# vim run make through screen

Tags: vim, makefile, gnu-screen

Due to some complicated environmental variables required, I have chosen to run Make through GNU screen. Using the screen vim plugin, I have the following setup in my .vimrc:

`map <Leader>mm :call ScreenShellSend("cd ".expand("%:p:h")." && make 2>&1 | tee /path/to/errorfile") <CR>`

Roughly translated, this will run make in the current working directory through an existing screen session with all of the required environment variables preset. I can then see the output of that command in a separate terminal window.

My question is, assuming I output the results of make to a text file, how do I tell automate the vim make process to:

A.) set make to use a vimscript function, i.e. call SreenShellSend() instead of an external program.

B.) set errorfile to /path/to/errorfile

Comment: I don't know enough about sending remote commands to screen to answer this completely, but check out the Vim help for `makeprg`.  If you can construct the command-line equivalent of your ScreenShellSend() command, you can set `makeprg` to that.  Then `set errorfile=/path/to/errorfile` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot set `'makeprg'` to a Vim function or command, it has to be a shell program. (I wish for an enhancement that treats commands starting with a colon as Vim commands, similar to the `:help` exception in `'keywordprg'`, but haven't come around to implementing this.)

There are workarounds, though. One is to use `vim --remote-send` as `'makeprg'` and use this other temporary Vim instance to call back into the original Vim. What I do though is overriding the `:make` command through the [cmdalias.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) for those buffers. That alias then simply `:call`s my function.

Once you're able to invoke a Vim function, setting the `'errorfile'` is just a matter of putting a function wrapper around `ScreenShellSend()` and setting it in there.